# Phonegap, Cordova, xCode 4.4 and Mountain Lion

Tags: templates, cordova, xcode4, cordova-2.0.0

Yesterday I cleaned my hard drive and I updated my OSX to Mountain Lion. I installed xCode 4.4, and after, I downloaded and installed the PhoneGap 2.0.

The problem is that I can't create projects using the template of Cordova Project... like I usually do before...

Does anybody know where is the problem?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this guide

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

The template method for creating projects has changed in PhoneGap 2.0 I believe.

Comment: I know now where was the problem... You must install the command line in xCode... I found this video http://outof.me/phonegap-2-0-getting-started/

Comment: I've downlaoded the PhoneGap from the webpage but It does not contain any dmg/pkg file.

Answer (score 3):

Check this tutorial as the official one is outdated
http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/phonegap-2-1-0-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-10-8-from-download-to-ios-app-store/

Comment: great! i will try it now